# Error: Invalid "keyPath" option supplied in AWS IoT Node-red

Tags: aws-iot

I am getting this message when trying to use aws iot with node red on Raspberry Pi, using node-red-contrib-aws-iot.

I've tried putting the certs in various directories, ~/, ~/.node-red/, ~/.node-red/certs/ etc but always get the same error

Does anyone know where is the correct place for the certs, and what is the correct corresponding key path for the aws-iot-broker node Security tab settings?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here, We need to add client id along with the name of the certificate names, then only we can able to connect it.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, be aware that there has been a change in the recent versions

File specification for the certificates changed! So you might have to change the filenames of your certificates.

See https://github.com/cuongquay/node-red-contrib-aws-iot/commit/bba0df4b0fa8e13a60f98c0ba05e57f423ad9bf8

Until February it was:

```
clientId + '-private.pem.key'
clientId + '-certificate.pem.crt'
```

Now it must be:

```
clientId + '.private.key'
clientId + '.cert.pem'
```